# git pull stuck from Hudson

Tags: git, hudson

I have a number of Hudson build jobs that were working properly. These are setup to use a Git repository that is hosted in [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com). Now all these builds are getting stuck at "git pull". Hudson is running under the system user named "hudsonuser". If I log in to the server using this user and go to the "workspace" directory of a job and do a "git pull" there then it works.

I have tried restarting Hudson, restarting the server and resetting the public key of the hudsonuser to no avail.

Any help/suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does the git pull command hang forever, or do you get a timeout after a while ?  If the latter, please post the error output.

Comment: The git pull command is hanging forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because a few large files being pushed by some developers. These files were of size 80 MB on average. After removing these files the issue went away.